# ON drawing on screen, it draw and replace the layout that make it jump

Tags: html, css

On the page : http://hebe-tutorat.org/ when loading, it display the top image scrooler with a lot of space (?!) and finally make it close to the to, and replace it near, that make the whole image jump (redraw?)....

question : what make it do that, and how to fix it...

Never ever seen that before, so i have no clue how to fix that... and what to google to find a solution, and it's in firefox on mac, sad... FF become IE ?

Comment: it is caused by javascript adding new elements after page load,, why do you think it is caused by css?

Comment: on reset.css, over one style.css over one custom.css changing the padding or margin ? I dont know

Comment: if you have to shovel an element to the page with javascript, just create a blank placeholder for the element with predefined height, so other elements won't jump after this placeholder is replaced with actual element..

Comment: I have no idea what is doing that.... div, height, text, line height.. i dont know where to look !... i dont think about java is the culprit !

Comment: looks like not new elements, but change in font...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i gave it a better look using Firefox and NoScript - you change the font of menu items using javascript:

[image]